# How do I remove all elements from a list which is a subsequence of another bigger element in the same list in python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list of lists which looks like this:

[['rest'],['look'],['rest','look'],['resting','look],['apple','mango'],['apple','man'],['apple','banana','mango'],['rest','resting','look','looked','it','spit']]

All the elements which are a substring/subsequence of another element must be removed. For example elements `['rest']` and `['look']` are already present in list elements `['rest','look']` and `['rest','resting','look','looked','it','spit']`, so they must be removed from the final list. Also, element `['rest','look']` is subsequence of ['rest','resting','look','looked','it','spit']`, so it should be removed. Similarly,` ['resting','look']`is a substring of`['rest','resting','look','looked','it','spit']`, so it also must be removed.The element ['apple','mango'] as it is a subsequence of ['apple','banana','mango'] should be removed but ['apple','man'] should not be removed as it is not a common subsequence.The output has to be a list and not a set.

I tried this:

```
x = [['rest'],['look'],['rest','look'],['resting','look'],['apple','mango'],['apple','man'],['apple','banana','mango'],['rest', 'resting', 'look', 'looked', 'it', 'spit']]

res=[]

found=0

for i in x:
   for item in i:
     for j in x:
          for item1 in j:
            if item == item1:
               found=1
     if found==0:
          res.append(item)

print res
```

The output I am getting is an empty list. The desired output is:

```
[['apple','man'],['apple','banana','mango'],['rest','resting','look','looked','it','spit']]
```

Comment: You can simply flatten the `list` and convert it to a `set` and that should do the job.

Comment: If my answer solves it please do accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a set comprehension instead, by flattenning the list into a set.

```
x = [['rest'],['look'],['rest','look'],['resting','look'],['rest', 'resting', 'look', 'looked', 'it', 'spit']]
In [2]: results = {s_ for s in x for s_ in s}
In [2]: results
Out[3]: {'it', 'look', 'looked', 'rest', 'resting', 'spit'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here's what you have tried to implement. I don't think you need variable `found`, you can just check for each item in sub-lists (e.g. `['rest', 'look']` is already *append*ed to `res`.

```py
x = [['rest'], ['look'], ['rest', 'look'], ['resting', 'look'], ['rest', 'resting', 'look', 'looked', 'it', 'spit']]
res = []
for L in x:
    for item in L:
        if item not in res:
            res.append(item)


print(res)
# ['rest', 'look', 'resting', 'looked', 'it', 'spit']
```